# A word for the relatives of a deceased?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word in English that refers to the closest relatives (usually the ones who lived with the dead person under one roof) of a recently (approximately no more than 1 month) dead person? Other friends and relatives usually come to such a group of people to comfort them of their loss of someone very precious to them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *[bereaved](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/bereaved?searchDictCode=english)*:

> verb
>
> (be bereaved)
>   Be deprived of a close relation or friend through
>   their death:
>   *she had recently been bereaved*
>
> (as adjective bereaved) *bereaved families*
>
> (as noun the bereaved) *those who counsel the bereaved*
>
> *ODO*

Answer (score 1):

People attending a funeral are known as ***mourners***.

The closest relative(s) of the deceased can be said to be ***the chief mourner(s)***.

Members of the deceased's family might also be designated as *close family mourners*.

I am not sure that these descriptions extend beyond the time of the funeral and its wake, however. A week later they might be known simply as ***the bereaved***.

Comment: They are also referred to as _surviving members of the family_ . Specifically, in the obituary, they are mentioned in this manner:  {He/she/Mr. A/Mrs.B} _is survived by_ {list of immediate family, including where they live if not local} and {x number of unnamed grandchildren & great-grandchildren}